# Are United Airlines employees authorized to ask TSA screening questions?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

While I was waiting at my gate (after security check) to fly to San Francisco from Europe, the gate agent asked me to go to a "Document Check" station manned by other United Airlines employees. At this station, the employee asked me to show not just my covid test and passport, but also my permanent residence documents. Most questionably, he also asked about my itinerary and my relationship with my travel companions.

I was pretty shocked that an airline employee is allowed to ask such questions, so I complained to a United Airlines supervisor at the gate. The supervisor told me that these are "TSA questions" and that it is common for United employees to ask these questions.

This is the first time I experience such questioning after many flights back into the US. Is it truly allowed and common?

Comment: I've had to show my documents to the airline when both flying *to* and flying *from* the US on various occaisions.  And to take a page out of an IT book.  "Security isn't a single point action, it's a process"

Comment: Greyhound to Canada does the same thing back when they were operating.

Comment: Describing them as "TSA questions" is technically inaccurate, as the TSA has nothing to do with customs and immigration enforcement (they just want to make sure you're not an imposter and not on the no-fly list). "CBP questions" would probably be more correct.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The airline not only can, but legally is required to, confirm you have the correct documents required in order to enter the US. This would normally include things like visa/immigration documentation, but also currently includes COVID-19 documentation (specifically for the US, proof of a negative test within the previous 3 days).

The question regarding your relationship to your travel companions was likely related to the current travel ban on specific travelers entering the US, which some passengers can be exempted from based on their relationship to a US Citizen or Legal Permanent Resident.  As a permanent resident you are exempt from this ban, as are you spouse/children (below a certain age), and it may have simply been easier for the agent to "approve" your companion under these rules (if they applied) rather than based on their own status.

There are also several other procedures which the airline is required to perform on behalf of the US government for flights headed to the US, such as providing additional security screening for selected passengers (those selected by the US Government to receive 'SSSS' on their boarding passes, which stands for 'Secondary Security Screening Selection').

This is all completely legal, and if you refuse to comply you will be denied boarding. If the airline fails to carry out such screening they can be penalized, starting with fines, but potentially up to the point of losing their ability to have flights to the US.

Comment: Thank you! For context, my itinerary is Lisbon -> Frankfurt -> San Francisco. I absolutely agree that airlines can check for documentation, and I already went through that check before baggage security at the check in counter in Lisbon. That's normal and expected.

What's unexpected is that they checked again in Frankfurt when I'm already at my gate (as described in my question). I suppose since Frankfurt is the stop before entry into the US, they want to and are allowed to check again?

Comment: It's not uncommon to have that kind of check at the gate before a flight to the US. You could reach that gate in any number of ways, and United doesn't necessarily trust that an agent working on behalf of another airline in another country has checked what they need to check, since United is ultimately responsible for who they fly to the US and can be fined if they transport someone they shouldn't have, especially with COVID as the rules are more complicated.

Comment: I’d just note that the sole distinction is that the airline agent is not a government employee and thus you are not under a legal obligation to give out valid answers to them. If you try to walk away from a CBP pre-clearance desk you’ll get in trouble. If you walk away from an airline agent and forfeit your flight, the worst penalty is that you lose your ticket.

Comment: @JonathanReez I wouldn't be surprised if the information somehow found its way to CBP which could flag the person involved for further scrutiny for subsequent attempts to fly to the US.

Comment: @Doc This is good answer but I don't think it's quite correct. I recently experienced that too and the level of questioning was WAY beyond I have ever seen and quite different from what I would consider "normal". Something must have changed recently. See my "pseudo answer" below for more details (unless the mods delete it, since it's not an answer)

Comment: @Hilmar at least in my experience it's a complete crapshoot what happens during international travel.  A couple years ago I got checked heavily both on arriving and returning home (luggage checks at both borders), a couple weeks ago I got waved through at both locations and they didn't even issue a declaration form at the US border control (well they did but you didn't have to fill anything out, they just gave me a blank form they signed).  No luggage check at all at either border. My traveling partner wasn't even a US citizen and they didn't even ask a single question.

Comment: I would also add that at the gate at the terminal for the flight to the US there were people being pulled off to the side for thorough luggage screening and questioning (like the OP describes), but it seemed random or perhaps based on the status or risk assessment of the passenger (non-US residents being more likely to be searched)

Comment: Do you have a link to more information about the travel ban? The guidelines are changing constantly and I'd love to be pointed to the up-to-date info

Comment: I was asked about why I chose to study in Europe in a rather hostile tone once for a flight to US ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, didn't see SSSS on the boarding pass and had supplied a known traveler number.

Comment: @JonathanReez the airline is obligated to fly you back.

Comment: All the things I see described in the comments  have been standard for decades when flying from South America to the USA.

Comment: @JonathanReez "If you try to walk away from a CBP pre-clearance desk you’ll get in trouble":  I don't believe this for a second, barring specific situations such as transit passengers who lack documents to stay in the preclearance country.  What sort of trouble do you imagine one would get into?

Comment: @phoog you won't be arrested of course but CBP could put a black mark in your profile that would make future visits to the US difficult

Answer (score 12):

Flights to the US have been subjected to additional checks for quite a few years now. Can't quite remember if that started after the shoe-bomber attempt or after the liquid bomb scare.

In many cases:

- There can be separate check-in areas for flights to the US, with additional questioning/verification before getting access to the check-in area;
- There is very often additional questioning/verification at the gate, before boarding.

The additional checks may involve:

- Documentation, including passports, visas, ESTA, etc. (CBP-related)
- Security questions (TSA-related)
- Additional searches of your luggage (TSA-related)

Of course, all this cannot be done by CBP or TSA officials abroad (except, for some of them, in airports which have CBP pre-clearance), so they are performed by local personnel working for the airlines. In many cases it's outsourced to security companies (the same kind of people you may see manning the general security checks), in some it may be handled by airline personnel / ground handling companies. Or it could be a combination of both.

In some situations, if you have already been subject to those additional checks before check-in (at the same airport), they'll place a sticker on your passport or some other identifying mark which lets them know you've already been checked by someone they trust to have performed the correct checks (and possibly, someone who is accredited to do so), and this will reduce checks at the gate (though not necessarily eliminate all of them). If you're in transit, this is a lot less likely, and you're bound to be checked again at the gate.

Comment: (+1) Anecdotally and judging by their accent, I had the feeling the people questioning passengers were actually Americans (unlike regular luggage screening or ground handling personnel). I also assume they couldn't be TSA employees but I have been wondering about that.

Comment: They probably hire people with better english skills than average, which may lead to them hiring US nationals living locally. It may even be possible that they need to have US citizenship to be accredited, though that would seem to be a little overkill.

Comment: I would like to believe you can always ask a questioner for ID, although I have no basis for that belief.

Comment: I distinctly remember that the person who questioned me about my travel plans and my eTA before I was allowed to join the checkin line for a flight to Canada from the UK (so english skills shouldn't be an issue) looked/sounded american (though the sticker he put on my passport reffered to "ICTS" which appears to be a dutch company).

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that it has become routine. It's been some times that I haven't seen a flight to the US without extra screening (systematic questioning in the waiting line before check-in and random additional hand luggage screening at the gate) above and beyond the regular document check and luggage screening you can expect for international travel outside the Schengen area. I have experienced this for US-bound flights leaving from multiple airports and with different airlines (it's not specific to United or Frankfurt).

I don't see on what basis it could be forbidden and I am pretty sure that you don't have any effective recourse or any practical way to avoid it.

Comment: The only practical way is to fly to Mexico and cross over the land border instead. No questions asked by the airline and no COVID test required to enter either Mexico or the US land border. You will get questions from CBP but I'm assuming OP is okay with that.

Answer (score 4):

Note: the airline isn't (really) legally a Delegate of the far-end country requiring documentation and vaccines; when you land, the entry Immigration/Customs of the country still do those processes again themselves.

for example, the airline cannot jail you if they detect fraud; those are rights/duties of Countries, not corporations.  They will REFER you to the National authorities, of course, if available.

ANSWER:
Airlines (and ships) do this because per International Treaties governing transit across borders, THEY are responsible for TRANSPORTING YOU BACK if you are denied entry at the other end of the flight.  So they do this to save themselves that expense.

Comment: Are they legally required to ship you back at there expense?

Comment: Broadly speaking, they are required to transport you back. However it does NOT need to be at their expense. They are allowed (and normally will) charge you for the return flight, although the catch is that they have no way to force the passenger to actually pay. More costly than the need to return the passenger, the airlines can be hit with substantial fines if they are found to be allowing passengers fly without the require documentation.

Comment: quoting https://airlines.iata.org/analysis/document-verification-travel-trouble

"...airlines then have to fly the incorrectly documented traveler back to their country of origin at their own expense, potentially taking a seat on a fight that they could have sold to a fare-paying passenger."

Comment: It's far more than the expense of unexpectedly accommodating the traveler on a flight back; there's also usually a fine of around $5,000 per person.  But if the airline is chronically negligent in checking documents, it risks losing its license to operate commercial flights to the destination country.

Answer (score 0):

What has happened to you is something more and more frequent, even more so since the pandemic began and the US entry restrictions.

From what I've been able to read, in many cases the airline is obliged to confirm that it has the required documents to enter the United States (T[SA precheck](https://www.usbirthcertificates.com/articles/how-to-get-tsa-precheck-documents) or ESTA or US visa,  even the passport!!).

With the arrival of the coronavirus, the airlines and their staff are also authorized to confirm extra requirements: PCR tests, vaccination proof, proof of having overcome the disease).

Although I understand your anger at the situation, it is something legal and can't be resorted to or avoided. If you are asked TSA evaluation questions, you will have no choice but to answer.

Comment: "in many cases the airline is obliged to confirm...": It is obliged to check this in every case, and there is a fine of a few thousand dollars if it fails to meet that obligation.  Such requirements have existed for over a century.

Comment: This does not seem to add much to the existing answers. Can you edit it to make it distinct?